# AMD RAPL power domains relations

Tags: x86-64, cpu, amd-processor, energy

Intel CPUs provide power monitoring via RAPL for several power domains - PKG, DRAM, PPx, Platform. Many sources describe these power domains and their relations, nice figure is in  *Khan, K. et al. “RAPL in Action.” ACM Transactions on Modeling and Performance Evaluation of Computing Systems (TOMPECS) 3 (2018): 1 - 26.*
[image]

AMD CPUs also have RAPL interface for power monitoring (as far as I know) PKG and Core domains, however I have not found any source presenting relations of these power domains. **Does PKG domain include Core domains?** One would expect that it does, but it is just an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"PKG domain includes of cores and also IO die and other in socket components."*

See amd_energy kernel driver issue: https://github.com/amd/amd_energy/issues/1

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a 1:1 mapping of package and core energy consumption for workloads that only use core ressources [1, Fig. 9b] this is **very** likely.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.00808